# native heap usage android

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

I need to know the amount of the heap usage of an applications and how the memory is allocated. Is there any chance to get a general picture of this? I want something like an hprof but more complete.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by modifying the firmware. Getting a heap dump of another application would be a serious security hole.

Comment: so is there no any chance to get the real heap allocated by the process?

Comment: @blackbelt: Not from an application. From DDMS, sure.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding.